# Having difficulty making a compound border

Tags: java, swing, border

I am having a little problem with getting my compound border to work. I have had a  play with borders previously and this seemed to be the best way to get my plan to work.

My plan is to quite simply have a box with opposite sides of the box being blue and red.

```
   container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder());
    container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 10, 0, 10, Color.red));
    container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 10, 0, Color.blue));
```

This is the code I have currently and I still cannot get the compound element working. I think I am missing something quite obvious, but I feel another pair of eyes might help which is why I am posting here.

Comment: A component can only have one `Border`, that's why the method is called `setBorder()` and not something like `getBorders().add()`. The function of a `CompoundBorder` is to hold two seperate `Border`s, a quick look into the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) would've answered this. Also, for future questions, please always include a compilable [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set 3 different borders to a component. You need to set border only once. Try following:

```
Border inner = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 10, 0, 10, Color.RED);
Border outer = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 0, 10, 0, Color.BLUE);
container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer, inner));
```

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html). You will find plenty of working examples showing how to do this. The tutorial can also be used as a reference for other Swing basics.